# Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer : Can't I have "Change" event handler together with "Progress" event handler?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

```
var player = Titanium.Media.createAudioPlayer({
    url : '101.mp3',
    allowBackground : false
});

var eventHandler = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Handler:" + JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
};

Ti.API.info("Setting up event handlers");
player.addEventListener('progress', eventHandler);
// player.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);

Ti.API.info("Starting player...");
player.play();
```

And the result is:

```
[INFO] :   Setting up event handlers
[INFO] :   Starting player...
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "progress": 927.4149659863946,
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "progress",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }  
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "progress": 1926.984126984127,
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "progress",  
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "progress": 2924.9206349206347,
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "progress",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "progress": 3926.7346938775513,
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "progress",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
```

so, clearly I get "progress" events...

Now if I uncomment the second addEventListener call:

```
player.addEventListener('progress', eventHandler);
player.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);
```

I get:

```
[INFO] :   Setting up event handlers
[INFO] :   Starting player...
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "state": 1,
[INFO] :       "description": "starting",
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "change",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "state": 2,
[INFO] :       "description": "waiting_for_data",
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "change",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "state": 3,
[INFO] :       "description": "waiting_for_queue",
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "change",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   Handler:{
[INFO] :       "state": 4,
[INFO] :       "description": "playing",
[INFO] :       "bubbles": true,
[INFO] :       "type": "change",
[INFO] :       "source": {},
[INFO] :       "cancelBubble": false
[INFO] :   }
```

No more "progress" events?

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Define two event handlers and add one per event.
Typically the way you handle audio progress events and change events is very different as well.

```
   var onProgressHandler = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Progress Handler:" + JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
    };

    var onChangeHandler = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Change Handler:" + JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
    };

    Ti.API.info("Setting up event handlers");
    player.addEventListener('progress', onProgressHandler);
    player.addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
```

Comment: Yes I used one handler for both events to keep this example short(er). But I fail to see why calling the same event handler for both events would make the slightest difference in this case?? I will try it but if it changes anything then I have deeply misunderstood the Javascript language.....

Answer (score 0):

Though both the AudioPlayer and a Window or any other view share the same [code](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/bc85170157d3bebc5de1d61a9fe6e34bce84a8c9/iphone/Classes/TiProxy.m#L829) to manage listeners, I cannot reproduce this with:

```
win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
win.addEventListener('singletap', listen);
win.addEventListener('doubletap', listen);
win.addEventListener('longpress', listen);
function listen(e) {
  console.log(e.type);
}
win.open();
```

However, since it looks like you have good reproducible use case, please do create a [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org) ticket so that we can fix this.